# Separate textboxes and buttons in css

Tags: css

I would like to have a robust CSS that would have all forms I have looking the same.

I encounter a problem when defining CSS properties for the buttons and textboxes

here is the css

```
#content .forms input {
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

I would like to have CSS for the buttons separate from the buttons but the

"#content .forms 'input' "

makes then look the same. Any ideas on how i would go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add multiple classes to an element by separating the classes with a space.

```
<style>
    .FirstClass { color: #a9a9a9 }
    .SecondClass { font-size: 10pt; }
</style>
<input type='text' class='FirstClass SecondClass' />
```

Adding multiple classes can be confusing if you apply more and more classes to a single element.

Answer (score 6):

If you can ignore IE6 you could use the [attribute selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors):

```
input[type="text"] {

}

input[type="button"] {

}
```

If you can't, you will have to give your buttons/textboxes a class and apply styles to that class.

Comment: can i add a class to a class because already .forms is a class

Comment: show us the markup you have. You can use multiple classes on one element: <input class="SomeClass SomeOtherClass" ... />

Comment: Sure an element can have multile classes

Answer (score 1):

you can use [attribute selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html) like `input[type="submit"]`.